# GET-REQUEST via WebKit Swift 4 Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, webkit, get-request

I am trying to open a webpage via WebKit. I want to reach my server (which runs on a VM) with that URL: stockify/auth/google

It is working fine in Safari. But if I try doing this via code in Xcode it is showing me a blank webview:

```
let url = URL(string: "stockify/auth/google")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)
```

It is working fine if I use: let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.de")
I've read that i has something to do with the "http" but how can I solve this problem?

If I open this on my browser (safari) it directs me to this page:
[oAtuh Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOXLR.png)
How can I have this result on my webView?

Comment: What URL are you trying to open in the web view? I don't think `stockify/auth/google` is a valid URL, since it's missing a scheme and tld.

Comment: Yes I've found out yesterday that it's not a valid URL for swift. Even though I can open the url in Safari on the simulator. But if you try to open it in the app via WebView or you open Safari via the app with that url it's not working.